# Using Android Data Binding in API level 23

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

.NET developer new to the Android world here. I'm currently developing an app for the Vuzix M300 smart glasses. The Vuzix SDK uses Android 6.0 API Level 23. I would also like to use Android's Data Binding Library, but I'm having trouble getting my project to build with that enabled. My app build.gradle file originally was setup as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Vuzix Corporation:Vuzix M300 SDK:23'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        dataBinding { enabled = true }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

ext {
    support_version = '23.4.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

But that was giving me errors so I added the following line after some searching online:

```
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$support_version"
```

This resulted in a different error, which is where I'm stumped:

> Program type already present:
>   android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present:
>   android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat,
>   sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

It seems the v4 support repository I added is causing conflicts with the v7 I already have in there, but I'm not sure how to get around this. I've run into the same error but for AsyncTasks as well.

Does anyone have any ideas? Would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please add all lines of build errors so we able to find the issue

Comment: Updated with the only other line from the build error, not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to explicitly add `implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$support_version"` support library since V7 compat library implicitly depends on V4.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. After removing that line, syncing the gradle changes and building, I still get the same error unfortunately.

Comment: @pantoast just clean and rebuild or Invalidate cache